# Linq return distinct values from table if not exist in another

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

I am trying to return all distinct rows from Staging below where Staging.CenterCode does not exist in Centers.CenterCode.

At the moment Stagings has around 850 distinct CenterCodes and Centers is empty so I should be getting all of the distinct rows, but count begs to differ :)

Any ideas?

```
 var query =
                (from s in db.Stagings
                 join t in db.Centers on s.CenterCode equals t.CenterCode into tj
                 from t in tj.DefaultIfEmpty() 
                 where s.CenterCode != t.CenterCode
                 select s.CenterCode).Distinct();

            var c = query.Count();
```

I only need the unique columns from staging so not sure if I actually need a join with the above as I am not ever using data returned from Centers - I have however tried both and get the same 0 value for count.

Any ideas?

Comment: Any of the answers help you?

Answer (score 0):

I would not use a join, but use a Contains.

```
var centerCodesQuery = db.Centers.CenterCode
    .Select(x => x.CenterCode);
var query = db.Staging
    .Where(x => !centerCodesQuery.Contains(x.CenterCode))
    .Select(x => x.CenterCode)
    .Distinct();
var c = query.Count();
```

Answer (score 0):

the `join` is an inner join. So, if none of the rows in 1 table match the other table on the specified identifier then it will return 0. In yours you are trying to join 1 table with 850 distinct rows with an empty table. This will return 0.

If you actually want to return only those rows in 1 table that aren't in another you can use [Except](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386962(v=vs.100).aspx):

```
var query = (from s in db.Stagings
             select s.CenterCode)
             .Except(from t in db.Centers 
                     select t.CenterCode);

var c = query.Count();
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to implement [antijoin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Antijoin_.28.E2.96.B7.29) via [left outer join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311040.aspx#Anchor_2), which is one of the possible ways, but in order to make it work, you need to change

```
where s.CenterCode != t.CenterCode
```

to

```
where t == null
```